# Not able to install siesta 1.4.2

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

Not able to install siesta 1.4.2. By default, it is installing 1.1.1.

Also getting below error with 1.1.1

> :-1: unexpected duplicate task: CompileXIB
>   /Users/volansys/Documents/workspace/Projects/Rheem_2/RheemEcoNet/Pods/Siesta/Source/SiestaUI/ResourceStatusOverlay.xib
>   (in target 'Siesta')

Comment: Did you check `Compile Resources` of `Build Phases`? Sound like you have a duplicate entry.

Comment: It looks like you're installing it with CocoaPods. Is that correct? What does your `Podfile` look like? Do you have a `Podfile.lock` that is pinning it to the older version? This question needs a _lot_ more detail to be answerable….

Comment: P.S. Your problem is that it’s installing the old version; Siesta 1.1.1 probably will not work on any recent version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update your pod, your pod is using the 1.1.1 version of the Siesta, meaning it is fetching the 1.1.1 version. I just did a pod install with

```
pod 'Siesta'
```

inside my pod file and I got the 1.4.0 version of it. try to update your pod with the following command

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

this will update it! I know it looks strange but that's what they say in their website!